# Customers having a problem logging onto our website

Tags: magento-1.7, https, apache, linux

We are having some customers face an issue when loading our website and they are receiving this message.

I have tried to type the link that it says but nothing is coming up. Can anyone suggest what I can do to help this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a server-related issue.

When has this website been released? Is it possible the DNS has not all been propaged yet?

Comment: The website has been running for the past 5/6 years. It works for a majority of people, but a handful people are getting this message. I'm not to sure, how would i go about checking the DNS?

Comment: Never mind then, it's a dead end as DNS take a maximum of 72h to fully propage... Sorry :(